# Not found image and .js inside static folder Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I am creating web app with Google App Engine and I have add directory `static` with three directories inside: `javascript, images, css` and I point to some image and script from jinja2 template (path is 100% ok) but when I run from launcher in browser there is not image

```
<img class="map" src="../static/images/demo.png" width="100" height="100" usemap="#sea">
```

Does anyone know what can be a problem ?

Answer (score 1):

I am new to GAE so I forgot to add to `app.yaml`

```
- url: /static/images
  static_dir: static/images

- url: /static/javascript
  static_dir: static/javascript
```